# круглый векторный индикатор прогресса

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Делаю индикатор прогресса.
 Изначально планировал поиграться градиентами, но оказалось(внезапно!) нужна поддержка `IE9`.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, пример реализации или направление для поиска. Пробовал svg, но там, насколько я понял дуга уже задаётся через `<path/>` и точки + непонятно, как затухание линии реализовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, gray 60%, red);
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 90px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="inner">13%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для поддержки `IE`, вы можете использовать библиотеки, такие как `Snap.SVG` и анимировать атрибут `stroke-dasharray` с `JS` :

```js
var count = $(('#proc'));
$({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: count.text() }, {
  duration: 5000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function () {
    count.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter)+ "%");
  }
});

var s = Snap('#animated');
var progress = s.select('#progress');

progress.attr({strokeDasharray: '0, 251.2'});
Snap.animate(0,251.2, function( value ) {
    progress.attr({ 'stroke-dasharray':value+',251.2'});
}, 5000);
```

```css
#proc{
font-size:20; 
text-anchor:middle;
}
#anketa {
font-size:18;
fill:#CED0CF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<svg id="animated" width="100%" height="40%" viewbox="0 0 500 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet">
  <g transform="translate(0 0)">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="none" stroke="#E1E4E3" stroke-width="2"/>
  <path id="progress" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="2" stroke="#FFA6A7" fill="none"
        d="M50 10
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80
           a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80">
  </path>
  </g>
  <text id="proc" x="50" y="50"  dy="7" >100%</text> 
  <text id="anketa" x="-180" y="50" >Анкета заполнена на</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот как я в итоге решил задачу на основе ответа от **@Alexandr_TT**. Может кому пригодится.

```js
$('#progress-test').on('input', function() {
  $('#progress-bar').attr('stroke-dasharray', (301.6 * +this.value / 100) + ',301.6');
  $('#percent').text(this.value + '%');
  if (+this.value > 70) {
    $('#progress-bar').attr('stroke', '#f00');
  } else {
    $('#progress-bar').attr('stroke', 'url(#gradient)');
  }
})
```

```css
.progress__val {
  fill: #7b7b7b;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.progress__null,
.progress__bar {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

.progress__null {
  stroke: #e4e7eb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="100" id="progress-test">
</p>
<svg id="progress" width="100px" height="100px" viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet">
  <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="10%" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" gradientTransform="rotate(-50, .5, .5)">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#e4e7eb"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
  <g>
   <circle class="progress__null" r="48" cy="50" cx="50"></circle>
   <circle class="progress__bar" id="progress-bar" r="48" cy="50" cx="50" transform="rotate(-90 50 50)" stroke-dasharray="0,301.6" stroke="url(#gradient)"></circle>
  </g>
  <text dy="7" y="50" x="52" id="percent" class="progress__val">0%</text>
 </svg>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT , все равно с градиентом беда. Никак не задать ему направление вдоль линии. Видел, конечно, вариант с разбитием скриптом на мелкие отрезки и задание отдельных градиентов, но на мой взгляд - это перебор.