# SVG полукруг разбить на 3 равные части

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, svg

У меня приложение на `Vue.js`  и мне нужно прогресс-бар создать. Я использую Svg, потому что другие варианты не подойдут. Как можно разбить SVG-полукруг на равные части. У меня получается сплошная линия. Пытался манипулировать атрибутом `stroke-dasharray`, но не получается.
Необходимо получить такой вид:

[image: прогресс-бар]

я пока добился такого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мой код:

```html
<div class="radial">
        <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" width="100" viewBox="0 0 200 200" data-value="40">
            <path class="bg" stroke="#ccc" d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0"  fill="none"/>
            <path class="meter" stroke="#D15F45" d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0" fill="none" pathLength="100" stroke-dasharray="38, 100"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: Не совсем. Так я тоже делал. Но мне необходимо, чтобы были именно 3 равных сектора. У меня, например, 100% = 30, а непосредственно проценты заполнения будут передаваться переменной. Так вот, если вы в своем примере измените `pathlength` на 30, то увидите, что результат совсем не такой.

Comment: @MaximLensky, да. Только как  в таком случае передавать проценты заполнения? Он не всегда заполнен на 100%

Comment: В этом и вся суть. Динамически менять не получается - секторы "бегают". Нужно именно в статике эти три сектора всегда иметь неподвижными и неизменяемыми, а заполнять уже с помощью переменной.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Самый простой вариант, если фон белый, можно закрыть 2мя белыми линиями, идущими от центра:**

```js
requestAnimationFrame(draw)
function draw(dt) {
  document.querySelector('.meter').setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `${dt/10%100}, 100`);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}
```

```html
<div class="radial">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" data-value="40">
    <path class="bg" stroke-width="22" stroke="#ccc" d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0"  fill="none"/>
    <path class="meter" stroke-width="22" stroke="#D15F45" d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0" fill="none" pathLength="100" stroke-dasharray="38, 100"/>
    <path stroke="white" stroke-width="5" d="M100 100 l-100 -100"/> 
    <path stroke="white" stroke-width="5" d="M100 100 l100 -100"/> 
  </svg>
</div>
```

---

---

**Вариант с масками**

Тут для бордера используется другая фигура, с большей толщиной линии, от которой маской мы отрезаем ненужное:

```html
<body style="margin:0; overflow:hidden">
    <svg  height="200" width="640">
      <defs>
      <mask id="m">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
        <path stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M100 100 l100 -100"/> 
        <path stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M100 100 l-100 -100"/> 
        <path fill="black" d="M100 100 l-115 100 l115 100 l115 -100z"/>    
      </mask>
      </defs>

      <g>
        <circle fill="none" stroke-width="25" stroke="#999" r="77" cx="100" cy="100"/>
      </g>
      
      <g transform="translate(220,0)">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
        <path stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M100 100 l100 -100"/> 
        <path stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M100 100 l-100 -100"/> 
        <path fill="black" d="M100 100 l-115 100 l230 0z"/>    
      </g>
      
<g transform="translate(440,0)">
        <circle mask="url(#m)"fill="none" stroke-width="25" stroke="#999" r="77" cx="100" cy="100"/>
      </g>
            <text text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central" font-size=55 x=210 y=100>+</text>
            <text text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central" font-size=55 x=420 y=100>=</text>
   </svg>
 </body>
```

---

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let meter = document.querySelector('path.meter');
let text = document.querySelector('text');
let arrow = document.querySelector('path.arrow');
let length = meter.getTotalLength();

requestAnimationFrame(draw)

function draw(dt) {
  progress(dt / 100 % 100);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}

function progress(value) {
  meter.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `${length/100*value}, ${length}`);
  arrow.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${-135+value*270/100} 100,100)`);
  text.innerHTML = Math.round(value);
}
```

```html
<svg height="175" viewBox="0 0 200 200">

  <defs>

    <mask id="mask1">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <path stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M100 100 l100 -100"/> 
      <path stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M100 100 l-100 -100"/> 
      <path fill="black" d="M100 100 l-115 100 l230 0z"/>    
    </mask>

    <mask id="mask2">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <path stroke="black" stroke-width="5" d="M100 100 l100 -100"/> 
      <path stroke="black" stroke-width="5" d="M100 100 l-100 -100"/>  
    </mask>

   </defs>
  
   <g fill="none">
     <circle mask="url(#mask1)" stroke-width="25" stroke="#999" r="77" cx="100" cy="100"/>
     <path mask="url(#mask2)" stroke-width="22" stroke="#ccc" d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0"/>
     <path mask="url(#mask2)" stroke-width="22" stroke="#d15f45" d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0" class="meter"/>
     <circle stroke-width="7" stroke="#ccc" r="33" cx="100" cy="100"/>
   </g>
   <text x="100" y="100" font-family="arial" font-size="22px" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central">0</text>
   <path class="arrow" transform="rotate(-135 100,100)" fill="#ccc" d="M100,65 l5,0 l-5,-10 l-5,10"></path>
 </svg>
```

**UPD: сделал как в вопросе, с циферками и стрелочкой**

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно!

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov рад помочь

Comment: Гэп между секторами надо в `d` менять, получается?

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov я сначала загнался с clip, поэтому так, скоро переделаю на толщину, если вы про второй вариант

Comment: Да, я про второй вариант. Кроме того, пытаюсь добавить границы(border) к `path class='bg'`, но тщетно. Мне нужны границы у серого полукруга (задний полукруг).

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov посмотрите так, однако чтобы сделать обводку надо уде выпендриваться, примерно как в этом сообщении https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962939/Как-сделать-круговую-диаграмму-зависимую-от-чекбоксов/962996#962996

Comment: Еще раз спасибо. А в `stroke-dasharray` это для примера было 100. В другом своем SVG я использую, например, 999. Ну вижу вы тоже на 1000 поменяли.))

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov но этого недостаточно, длина пути на iphone и desktop разные, я позже изменю второй пример, с телефона не удобно

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov с обводкой еще наколдовал немного, позже еще подрихтую

Comment: Я пытался плотно разобраться с SVG в целом. Может посоветуете "путь" для получения знаний? Или достаточно документации на MDN?

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov mdn хорош, но я больше по примерам учусь

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov запилил

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Чтобы твоя пила не затупилась (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT спасибо, в этот раз без d3, но уже с костылями :) из посчитанных фигур было бы легче стилизовать

Answer (score 10):

### Решение с помощью stroke-dasharray

У заданного пути максимальная длина равна `350px`
Вычисляется длина с помощью `getTotalLength()`

```html
 <input  type="button" value="Максимальная длина"  onclick="TotalLength()"/>
 <div>  
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" > 
 
         <path id="check" fill= "none" stroke ="grey" stroke-width ="1" 
         
   d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0" />
</svg> 
</div>
   <script>
         function TotalLength(){
          var path = document.querySelector('#check');
        var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
        alert("Длина пути - " + len);
        };
  </script>
```

Если нужно поделить на три равных сектора, то длина одного сектора будет равна `116.67px`
 Это сумма длин: черты - `110px` и пробела `6.67px`

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" data-value="40">
       <path class="bg" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="110 6.67" 
        d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0"  fill="none"/>
 </svg>
```

Более подробно, как делить окружности на равные части с помощью `stroke-dasharray` [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/760290/28748) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944006/28748)

Анимация заполнения первого сектора основана на изменении значения длины черты от нуля до максимального значения `110px`

`<animate id="an1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="0s;an3.end" values="0 110 0 240;110 0 0 240" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />`

Точно также заполняются по очереди остальные 2 сектора.

Я сделал сектора разного цвета, при необходимости можно присвоить один цвет.

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" data-value="40">
       <path class="bg" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="110 6.67" 
        d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0"  fill="none"/>
          
    <path  class="meter" stroke="green" stroke-width="20" 
     d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0"   fill="none"   stroke-dasharray="0 350" stroke-dashoffset="0" > 
     <! анимация заполнения зелёного сектора -->
     <animate id="an1"
          attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
          begin="0s;an3.end"
          values="0 110 0 240;110 0 0 240"
          dur="2s"
          fill="freeze" />  
    </path>   
                   <! анимация заполнения жёлтого сектора -->    
     <path  class="meter" stroke="gold" stroke-width="20" 
       d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0"   fill="none"   stroke-dasharray="0 350" stroke-dashoffset="0" >
     <animate id="an2"
           attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
           begin="an1.end" 
        values="0 116.67  0 110  0 116.67;0 116.67  110 0  0 116.67"
           dur="2s"
           fill="freeze" />  
   </path>   
          <! анимация заполнения красного сектора -->
      <path  class="meter" stroke="red" stroke-width="20" 
         d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0"   fill="none"   stroke-dasharray="0 350" stroke-dashoffset="0" >
        <animate id="an3"
              attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
              begin="an2.end"
              values="0 116.67 0 116.67 0 116.67;0 116.67  0 116.67 110 0"
              dur="2s"
              fill="freeze" />  
   </path> 
 </svg>
```

### Анимация стрелки указателя

`<animateTransform id="an_arrow" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="-10 100 100;255 100 100" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" />`

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" data-value="40">
       <path class="bg" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="110 6.67" 
        d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0"  fill="none"/>
          
    <path  class="meter" stroke="green" stroke-width="20" 
     d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0"   fill="none"   stroke-dasharray="0 350" stroke-dashoffset="0" > 
     <! анимация заполнения зелёного сектора -->
     <animate id="an1"
          attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
          begin="0s;an3.end"
          values="0 110 0 240;110 0 0 240"
          dur="2s"
          fill="freeze" />  
    </path>   
                   <! анимация заполнения жёлтого сектора -->    
     <path  class="meter" stroke="gold" stroke-width="20" 
       d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0"   fill="none"   stroke-dasharray="0 350" stroke-dashoffset="0" >
     <animate id="an2"
        attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
        begin="an1.end"
        values="0 116.67  0 110  0 116.67;0 116.67  110 0  0 116.67" dur="2s"
        fill="freeze" />  
   </path>   
          <! анимация заполнения красного сектора -->
      <path  class="meter" stroke="red" stroke-width="20" 
         d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0"   fill="none"   stroke-dasharray="0 350" stroke-dashoffset="0" >
        <animate id="an3"
           attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
           begin="an2.end"
           values="0 116.67 0 116.67 0 116.67;0 116.67  0 116.67 110 0"
           dur="2s"
           fill="freeze" />  
   </path> 
   
   <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="silver" />
    <path d="m62.4 134.1c0 2.8 13.6 7.4-2.6 5-2.7-0.4-10.7-0.2-10.7-0.2 0 0 4-13.1 4.1-19.1 0.1-6 9.2 11.5 9.2 14.3z" fill="silver">
    <animateTransform id="an_arrow"
       attributeName="transform"
       type="rotate"
       values="-10 100 100;255 100 100"
       dur="6s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"
       fill="freeze" />
    </path>
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="3" fill="#8E8E8E"  />
       
    </svg>
```

**Ссылки на связанные топики c заполнением прогрессбара и выводом процентов:**

[Круговой прогресс бар](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/628257/28748)

[Круговой процентный прогресс бар](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628312/28748)

[Круглый векторный индикатор прогресса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/784236/28748)

[Практические примеры применения масок svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/919186/28748)

Comment: Все ждал твоего ответа с подробными комментариями....)

Comment: на ios проблемка, похоже надо высчитывать реальную длину пути

Comment: @Stranger in the Q я считал длину пути с помощью `TotalLength()` Видимо ios не понимает stroke-dasharray c двумя, тремя парами атрибутов

Comment: @Alexandr_TT похоже что на ретине длина отличается

Comment: @Alexandr_TT спасибо за развернутый ответ с пояснениями, но меня это запутало окончательно.)) Не могу понять как остановить анимацию на конкретном значении. У меня, к примеру, 100% = 30, а заполнение я получаю из переменной. Допустим как мне остановить заполнение и стрелку на значении 20 из 30?

Comment: @Daniyal Lukmanov Не за что, был рад дать новую информацию к обучению SVG, но обычно к спасибо добавляют плюсик  к ответу :) На словах очень трудно объяснить в комментариях, то что вы хотите понять.  Задайте новый вопрос.Почитайте топики, на которые я уже дал ссылки. Сейчас добавлю новые ссылки на топики, где идёт заполнение прогрессбара с выводом процентов заполнения

Comment: @Daniyal Lukmanov Реализация вашего примера затруднена, тем что круг разбит на сектора. Поэтому в первом ответе `Stranger in the Q` применяет маски для имитации вырезов. Чтобы понять эту технику почитайте [топик по использованию масок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/919186/28748)   Я использовал в своем ответе `stroke-dasharray` Ваша задача сильно упростится, если у вас будет линия без разрывов и тогда можно будет использовать решения из ссылок, которые я привел в ответе.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Благодарю. Я немного модифицировал ваш ответ, привязал к переменным необходимые значения - сейчас все, как необходимо работает. )) Учиться многому нужно конечно. Но на то она и профессия - разработчик. )

Comment: @Daniyal Lukmanov покажите свой ответ, вы вполне можете его опубликовать прямо здесь. Ещё и плюсиков заработаете :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Я сейчас доработаю еще. У меня получается, что я беру основу из ответа Stranger in the Q с добавлением необходимых атрибутов, добавляю туда вашу реализацию стрелки, немного меняя атрибуты анимации. Скоро залью.

Answer (score 7):

Взяв за основу ответы `Stranger in the Q` и `Alexander_TT`, получил итог, который работает как необходимо в условиях моего проекта.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radial">
        <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" data-value="40">
            <defs>
                <mask id="mask1">
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
                    <path stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M100 100 l100 -100"/> 
                    <path stroke="black" stroke-width="2" d="M100 100 l-100 -100"/> 
                    <path fill="black" d="M100 100 l-115 100 l115 100 l115 -100z"/>    
                </mask>
                <mask id="mask2">
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
                    <path stroke="black" stroke-width="5" d="M100 100 l100 -100"/> 
                    <path stroke="black" stroke-width="5" d="M100 100 l-100 -100"/>  
                </mask>
            </defs>
            <circle mask="url(#mask1)" fill="none" stroke-width="25" stroke="#bfb09d" r="77" cx="100" cy="100"/>
            <path mask="url(#mask2)" fill="none" stroke-width="22" stroke="#FFF" d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0"/>
            <path mask="url(#mask2)" fill="none" stroke-width="22" stroke="#D15F45" d="M41 149.5a77 77 0 1 1 117.93 0" class="meter" pathLength="30" stroke-dasharray="22, 999">
                <animate id="an1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" from="0 0" to="22 999" dur="1s" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
            </path>  
            <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#bfb09d" class="arrow-circle"/>
            <path d="m62.4 134.1c0 2.8 13.6 7.4-2.6 5-2.7-0.4-10.7-0.2-10.7-0.2 0 0 4-13.1 4.1-19.1 0.1-6 9.2 11.5 9.2 14.3z" fill="#bfb09d">
                <animateTransform id="an_arrow" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="-10 100 100" to="186 100 100" dur="1s" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
            </path>
            <text font-size="36px" x="100" y="100" fill="#D15F45" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central">22</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

Данные для атрибутов(в примере хардкодом заданы `pathLength = 30` и `currentVal = 22`).

Comment: На всякий случай посмотрите мой обновленный ответ =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вы с `Alexander_TT` не перестаёте удивлять))

Comment: Однако чтобы сделать закругленные края, как на макете, я бы взял уже вариант с `d3.js`

Comment: Пока оставлю так. Если вдруг будет необходимость, то уже буду копать дальше.

Comment: @Daniyal Lukmanov поставил плюсик авансом, надеюсь подправите код, чтобы не было сообщений об ошибках

Comment: @Alexandr_TT ошибки, видимо из-за того, что я просто фрагмент из своего приложения на Vue выложил, чтоб показать откуда данные берутся. Я тогда изменю ответ без этих данных, чтоб просто оставить svg.